# Change text color to specific width in combination with a progress bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap 4 Website on which i have the following piece of hmtl code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto>
            <h2>Example heading text</h2>
            <h6>Example subheading text</h6>
        </div>
    </div
</div>
```

By default the color of the `<h2>`-Element is black. Now i'm calculating some stuff in the background which depends on this text. Let's say the result of the calculation is 75% i want to change the color of the text inside the `<h2>`-Element to red color but not the whole text - only the text till the width of 75% of the whole text width. (See my added example picture)

And with that there should be a progress bar under the text (so in my example code between the `<h2>`- und `<h6>`-Element. This bar should be filled with the same red color as the text above and should be populated with that color to the same width like the text (in the example 75%).

How can i do this with Javascript or jQuery? Or is there a css only solution i can use? But keep in mind, that i have multiple of these sections on my site for which i have to do this, and for every entry there could be other percentage values. Both elements should be colored like a slider or linear effect at the same time.

Here is a example picture for hopefully better understanding of what i want. If further details needed, please let me know.
[image]

Comment: I just got a crazy thought. What if you gave the text a gradient color and set the stops to the value from the progress bar and keep the pb hidden?

Comment: yes, could be an idea, but both - Text and the progress bar - should be visible and shown at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that you can query the current value from a progressbar and pass that value as the color-stop values for both color-stops. Kinda mimicking the progressbar.

I've added some sample code below based on the code you provided.

I didn't use a progressbar in this example.

Instead, I used a for loop and an alert to illustrate how the idea would work.
The loop brings iterations and the alert allows you to stop and see the color progression.

The iterations from the for loop can represent a process being tracked with a progressbar which has a value at any given time. By inserting that value into the gradient, your colored text will be updated.

Again, this is just an idea.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>page title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <style>
        .colorIt {
            display: inline-block;
            /*background-image: linear-gradient(to right, green 10%, black 10%);*/
            -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
            -webkit-background-clip: text;
            -moz-background-clip: text;
            background-clip: text;
        }

        h2 {
            font-size: 30px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

    </style>
    <script>
        // create script to inc and dec the color-stops on the gradient

        $(document).ready(function () {
            adjustColorStops();
        });

        function adjustColorStops()  //x=color-stop start color, y=color-stop end color values
        {
            // create a script to set the color-stops of the gradient
            // this is for the purpose of covering the left (green) color across to the right, eliminating the black color eventially
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < 110; i++)
            {
                alert(i);   // this is to slow things down so that you can see the increments of the color
                $(".colorIt").css("background-image", "linear-gradient(to right, green " + i + "%, black " + i + "%)");
                i += 9;
            }
            return;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
                <h2 class="colorIt">Example heading text</h2>
                <h6>Heading text is filled with a gradient.</h6>
                <!--<div class="progressBarDiv"></div>-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I will test it.